# convert values of List objects to string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects, Model is:

```
public class Rule
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

To get values of RuleName and IsValid from a list of Rules I did the following:

```
string.Join(", ", list.Select(rule=> new { rule.RuleName, rule.IsValid }))
```

Current output is in the following format:

```
{ RuleName = name1, IsValid = True}, { RuleName = name2, IsValid = False }
```

How to convert it to a format similar to the following without using loops?

```
name1 is True, name2 is False
```

Comment: whats so bad about loops? you could do it with linq but its still internally using loops

Comment: You can use string.format inside the select as **string.Join(", ", list.Select(rule => string.Format("{0} is {1}", rule.RuleName, rule.IsValid.ToString())));**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simple with `String.Join`, `Enumerable.Select` and string interpolation(C#6):

```
string.Join(", ", list.Select(r=> $"{r.RuleName} is {r.IsValid}"));
```